# Makefile: Foreach and eval's missing separators?

Tags: c++, makefile, separator

I have this in my Makefile:

```
# Build source files
define compile_rule
%.o : %.$1
        $$(COMPILE) $$(COMPILE_FLAGS) $$(CC_FLAGS) -o $$@ $$<
endef
$(foreach EXT, $(SRC_EXT), $(eval $(call compile_rule, $(EXT))))
```

However if I type `make` I get this error, why is this happening?

```
*** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
```

Comment: You should probably replace the 8 spaces with a tab in the line right above the `endef`

Comment: @pstrjds Ahh, dang, `make` pointed me to the wrong line, which is the $(foreach). Yes, that is right. Is it possible you write it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a tab instead of 8 spaces in the line right above the endef.